# Mac Sticky Keys

Tags: mac, keyboard

When I attempt to Enable Sticky Keys on my new Mac, the option appears greyed out in System Preferences. Although Slow Keys is available.

I use a Windows keyboard, because I type with a headstick. Should this matter? How do I enable Sticky Keys?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Kindly edit the question to include a screenshot of System Preferences where you find the option greyed out.